# How to address "is not numeric" error in R if the variable is already numeric?

Tags: r

I am having problems with `ReGenesees` package when creating a function/survey design.

Code used:

```
x_svy <- e.svydesign(data = data, 
                     ids = ~PSU_ID + SSU_ID, 
                     weights = ~final_weight_brgy,
                     strata = ~prov)
```

Error:

> Error in e.svydesign(data = data, ids = ~PSU_ID + SSU_ID, weights = ~final_weight_brgy,  :
> Weights variable final_weight_brgy is not numeric

However, if you check test the weight variable using `is.numeric()` function. Here's the result.

```
is.numeric(data$final_weight_brgy)
[1] TRUE
```

I have already tried the `as.numeric()` function even though I have checked the structure of the vector and found out that it is already numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your 'data' is a tibble and not a plain data.frame?

Tibbles behave differently under subsetting, especially when selecting a single column, as you can read here https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/subsetting.html

If 'data' is a tibble, you should convert it to a plain data.frame via as.data.frame() beforehand.

The next version of ReGenesees (2.3) will take care of the tibble "issue", so that users will no longer run into the trouble you experienced (I'm the author of ReGenesees).